# How to show that this function $f$ is continuously differentiable,

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vector-analysis, uniform-continuity

Given $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$, and assuming that the directional derivative $D_vf(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $x$ for $|v|=1$, show that $f \in C^1$.

This is an old exam question dating back to January 1990 that I would like to work through.

There is a hint given for this problem:

Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to show that

$$f(x+h) - f(x) - D_hf(x) = \int_0^1 D_hf(x+sh)-D_hf(x) \, ds$$

Some initial thoughts:

I need to show that f is both (totally) differentiable and the derivative $f'$ is continuous.  So, I need to show that $f$ is differentiable for arbitrary $x$ in its domain, i.e., show that

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac {|f(x+h) - f(x) - Ah|}{|h|} =0,$$

where A is a linear operator mapping $\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$.

**Is this "$A$" always the derivative matrix**?  The definitions seem very technical and abstract and doesn't say it explicitly -- the definitions just say "there exists a linear operator A such that ... the above limit is zero."

If $A$ is the derivative matrix, then for this problem, it would be a 1x2 matrix, i.e., the gradient of $f$.

So, the numerator in the limit looks pretty close to the left-hand side of the hint.

Also, $D_vf(x)$ is uniformly continuous in $x$, so

for $\epsilon$ >0, there exists $\delta>0$, such that $|x-y|< \delta$

implies that $|D_vf(x) - D_vf(y)| < \epsilon$.

**What does uniformly continuous in $x$ for $|v| = 1$** mean?  Does this mean that $D_vf(x)$ is uniformly continuous on the unit circle only and not in the interior?

Any suggestions on how to get started on this problem with the above information is welcome -- I'd also welcome any solutions, too.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, $A$ is the derivative matrix. Apparently your book is a little unclear on this, but because you can't divide by the vector $h$, the more familiar form of the definition of derivative doesn't work. It had to be recast in a form where the only division going on is by the scalar $|h|$.

And yes, you are only know that $D_vf(x)$ is uniformly continuous on the boundary of the unit circle, not the interior.

Comment: To clarify a bit: there is nothing said about the interior. $D_vf(x)$ could be unitformly continuous on the interior, or not.

Comment: Hi @PaulSinclair, I am working through it now - seems a bit scary and technical, but so far it's been manageable.  But, to use the FTC, can I assume that $D_vf(x)$ is continuous from 0 to 1?  I'm a little confused about what assumptions I can make about the directional derivative.  If it is uniformly continuous on |v| =1, must it be *at least* continuous from 0 to 1, so that I can integrate it?  It doesn't seem obvious...

Comment: The directional derivative is linear in $v$. In particular, $D_{av}f(x) = aD_vF(x)$ (Which BTW belies my earlier comments, but then my point then was that you weren't given this information, not that it necessarily was false.)

Comment: One more tricky thing:  when is $D_vf(x)$ *exactly* equal to the total derivative matrix?  I'm trying to show the left-hand side of the **hint** goes to zero, when divided by |h|, by using the uniform continuity assumption on the right-hand side of the hint.  But if I show that the left-hand side goes to zero, it is sort of like saying the directional derivative is exactly that linear operator that we were looking for -- that is, it is exactly the total derivative matrix, A.  What do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: Always $D_vf(x) = Df|_x v$. That is, the directional derivative in direction $v$ at the point $x$ is the total derivative matrix at $x$ applied to the vector $v$

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarity @PaulSinclair.  Just before this problem, I had proved that the equation you just mentioned, but for a specific f: $R^2 -> R$, i.e. $D_vf(x)$ = $\nabla f(x)$.$v$.  So, the equation you just showed applies to more general f, e.g., the equation applies whether f is a scalar field *or* a vector field? So that the equation is true in full generality (within advanced calculus / Euclidean space; I am not studying differential geometry)?  If so, I will be sure to try my best to remember this fact.  Thanks,

Comment: I feel like perhaps the equation is not true in full generality, since I don't think it makes sense to compute the gradient of vector fields - we normally compute the gradient of scalar fields...

Comment: It is not a gradient as such. In general, the derivative of a function $f$ from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ at a point $x$ is a linear operator - an $m \times n$ matrix. If $\phi$ is a curve in $\Bbb R^m$ that at $x$ is tangent to a vector $v$, then $f\circ\phi$ is a curve in $\Bbb R^n$ which at $f(x)$ is tangent to the vector $Df|_xv$. In the special case $n = 1$, the derivative is a linear functional from $\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R$, but by the inner product on $\Bbb R^m$, this functional can be converted to a vector. That vector is the gradient.